# Decode and Encode a property of type `Any` in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, codable

I have a class named `SPEFormFieldData`

```
import Foundation

class SPEFormFieldData: NSObject, Codable {

    public var fieldType: String?
    public var fieldDescription: String?
    public var fieldValue: Any?
    public var fieldTitle: String?
    public var fieldKey: String?

    override init() {
        self.fieldValue = ""
        super.init()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
```

As soon as I declare a property Any? it gives me an error that

**Type 'SPEFormFieldData' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'**,

**Type 'SPEFormFieldData' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'**

How can I parse a Any type and conform to Codable, I want to implement it as a class as well as I am restricted to keep it as `Any`

Comment: Short story: You cannot en-/decode `Any`. All supported types must conform to `Codable`, `Any` doesn't. And you are mixing up `Codable` with `NSCoding`

Comment: Thanks, can you give a brief as to why is `NSCoding` and `Codable` is getting mixed

Comment: `init?(coder` belongs to `NSCoding` (as well as the requirement to be a subclass of `NSObject`). The protocols `Codable` and `NSCoding` are not related to each other.

Comment: Can't `SPEFormFieldData` be made generic over `<T: Codable>`, and have `value:  T`?

Comment: Unrelated: don't prefix all of your variable names, just keep it simple: `type`, `description`, `value`, `title`, `key`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions on variable naming, will take care of that, how can I approach it using generics, if you could kindly shed some more light on it?

Comment: What exactly is `fieldValue` and does it really need to be of type `Any`?